# How to redirect all guest requests to login page in Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I want to direct all unauthorized users (aka not logged in) to the login screen *even* if they try to access a route that doesn't exist. Currently, my setup successfully redirects them if they try to access a page for authorized-only users, but if they try to access a page that doesn't exist, a normal 404 error is thrown; I would like these request to also redirect to the login page. Here's my current setup:

```
// for localization purposes, this needs to be outside the localization group
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

// for localization of auth as well as normal pages
Route::group([
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect'],
], function()
{
    // localized auth routes
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    // other localized auth routes...

    // if not logged in, redirect to login screen
    // (but throws a 404 if route doesn't exist)
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    });

    // Auth middleware group
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
    {
        // Post-Authentification Routes...
    });
});
```

Comment: What Laravel version do you use? There is big differences in 4 and 5, even between 5.0 and 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel by default throws `NotFoundHttpException` If a client trying to access a route that doesn't exists.

To handle this Exception you need to edit the method `render()` under `\app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

So to achieve your goal you need to have these steps

- Catch Exception (check if instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
- Check if user is authenticated or not.
- Redirect to '/login' if not Authenticated.

See you will get something like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException && !Auth::check()) 
            return redirect('/login');
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

And keep using `auth` middleware for every route you need only authenticated users to access.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Beside redirecting guests to login, this also seem to redirect logged in users to login page in case of 404. I'm trying to find a workaround but have problems, that's why I stumbled upon this question. It seems like Auth doesn't work in case of exceptions, since route was not matched and middlewares (StartSession and Authenticate) were not ran. (Laravel 5.3)

Comment: @Tadej https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/31fce5c503d872c5389ffbbae59310413f9f9966/app/Http/Kernel.php#L25-L54

Comment: @Tadej https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6cf003ae02582cf716c10a723ef6bc19690969e7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L110-L141